# Filter an array of objects by a N-length map of props with 3 states for each prop

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm doing a complex filter, for which I have an initial list of objects with unique ids.

And a map with N properties with a list of corresponding object copies for each prop; and three states for each prop: idle: 0, show: 1, hide: 2.

For now I managed to do this with lodash's `differenceBy` and `intersectionBy`. My filter function takes in an array of objects and mutates the array, by checking and filtering the array with every map prop.

**But concerning efficiency and growing number of complexity, should this kind of problem be solved differently?**

For example:

If this filter is applied to a big array of hex colors (length 100, 1000 or more)

`colors [1, 2, 3, ...1000]`

And prop map has a growing number of props, like tags, by which a user can mark colors and show/hide them on filter. Or at some point new prop states will be added.

```
prop1 0, 1, 2, ...10
prop2 0, 1, 2, ...10
prop3 0, 1, 2, ...10
...
prop100  0, 1, 2, ...10
```

**Should this kind of problem be solved via graph or matrix algorithms or some other method respectively? And, if yes, to what I should look into?**

My code for optimisation and efficiency concerns:

```js
const propMap = [
  { name: 'prop1', value: 0, items: [] },
  { name: 'prop2', value: 1, items: [ { id: 1}, { id: 2} ] },
  { name: 'propN', value: 2, items: [ { id: 2} ] },
];

const someArr = [
  { id: 1}, { id: 2}, { id: 3}, { id: 4},{ id: 5},
]

function filterByPropMap (arr) {
  // Filter hidden from array
  propMap.forEach(prop => {
    if (prop.value === 2) {
      arr = _.differenceBy(arr, prop.items, 'id');
    }
  });

  // Filter intersecting objects to show
  propMap.forEach(prop => {
    if (prop.value === 1) {
      arr = _.intersectionBy(arr, prop.items, 'id');
    }
  });
  
  return [...arr];
}

console.log(filterByPropMap(someArr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wha do you have `{ id: 1 }` twice in `someArr`? what is the wanted result?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. fixed it

Comment: The next answer seems to cover it

Answer (score 1):

In general, you very often [don't need Lodash](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore). Consider the following, which uses only vanilla ES6.

It returns `{ id: 1 }` twice, because it looks like the deduplication is an unintended side effect of your code. At least you never do so explicitly.

```js
const propMap = [
  { name: 'prop1', value: 0, items: [] },
  { name: 'prop2', value: 1, items: [ { id: 1}, { id: 2} ] },
  { name: 'propN', value: 2, items: [ { id: 2} ] },
];

const someArr = [
  { id: 1}, { id: 2}, { id: 3}, { id: 4},{ id: 1},
];

function filterByPropMap(arr) {
  const hiddenItems = propMap
    .filter(p => p.value === 2)
    .map(p => p.items)
    .flat();

  const intersectingItems = propMap
    .filter(p => p.value === 1)
    .map(p => p.items)
    .flat();

  const isEqual = (a, b) => a.id === b.id;

  return arr
    .filter(v => !hiddenItems.some(h => isEqual(h, v)) &&
      intersectingItems.some(i => isEqual(i, v)));
}

console.log(filterByPropMap(someArr));
```